Why pay repo to finance bond position instead of reverse repo?
Assume I would like to hold a long bond, short future position over $n$ days. My current understanding is one must pay daily repo to finance the bond position, i.e. the below diagram. However, it seems strictly better to just reverse repo—in this case I will hold the bond overnight, receive the coupons like before, and now I receive repo interest instead of paying it. Yes, I don't "own" the bond in the traditional sense since it will be repurchased, however it seems like I could use this to satisfy cash and carry arb throughout the holding period and then on $n-1$ days actually buy the bond and deliver it into the short future position. It would be equivalent to cutting out the blue square in the diagram and just having the red square interact with the bond market.
What am I missing?


if you reverse the bond - you are borrowing the bond vs lending cash. you dont accrue the coupons. The coupon accrues to the lender of the bond..

This is true, but see below for an even more serious issue that makes the trade not work.

Furthermore the scenarios are not directly comparable. Transacting a repo to finance a bond purchase assumes that cash is not already held by the party (and therefore the need to finance). Reverse repoing a bond assumes that cash is held by the party since it will be provided as the cash collateral in the transaction. If cash is already available, then a simple bond purchase can be completed without the need for financing anyway. The question is practically non-sensical.

This idea doesn’t work.  If you do a reverse repo (invest cash vs borrowing the bond), you do not have exposure to the bond price.  The bond is returned to the counterparty, regardless of what price movement has occurred.  Hence if you sell futures against the reverse repo, you will be outright short the bond market.
